# Repeating same analysis decreases completion time. How to avoid that?

Tags: alloy

I noticed that repeating the same analysis several time decreases drastically the time needed for completion.
In my case, a generation that takes 1700ms in the first run takes a mere 200ms after several repetitions.

I guess that the Analyser, or the underlying SAT-solvers are keeping track of previous analysis, and that's certainly all for the better in most of the case.

But currently I would like to have a more or less constant completion time. So my question is :

(tl;dr)
**Is there a way to empty the Analyzer "cache" (other than restarting the Analyzer) ?**

**EDIT**

I just made several run of this model of mine and here is what I get :

**run #1:**
113309 vars. 3023 primary vars. 298922 clauses. **1964ms**.

**run #2:**
113309 vars. 3023 primary vars. 298922 clauses. **1081ms**.

**run #3:**
113309 vars. 3023 primary vars. 298922 clauses. **514ms**.

**run #4:**
113309 vars. 3023 primary vars. 298922 clauses. **380ms**.

**run #5:**
113309 vars. 3023 primary vars. 298922 clauses. **342ms**.

**run #6:**
113309 vars. 3023 primary vars. 298922 clauses. **438ms**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed the same behavior many times, and I've never been certain about why it happens.  As far as I know, neither the Alloy Analyzer nor Kodkod maintains an explicit cache of any sort (of course, there are caches used within a single translation/execution, but I don't think they are carried over between executions).

My simple explanation is that the first "slow" run is due to "cold start".  One argument for that is that if you open two unrelated Alloy models, and first execute a command from the first model, then execute a command from the second model, the second execution (in my experience) still runs "faster" than when the same command is executed from cold start.

Comment: I think it's a bit more than a cold start, because it keeps improving time after time. I edited my question by adding the performance of several runs.

Comment: That's exactly the behavior I noticed in the past.  In your example, the first run is probably slow due to cold start.  All other runs are kind of similar; there is also some nondeterminism/randomization going on in the SAT solver, so repeated runs of the same problem rarely result in exactly the same times.  I don't, however, exclude the possibility that there is something going on in the Alloy Analyzer also affecting the total time.  Both Alloy's translation to Kodkod, and Kodkod's translation to SAT are deterministic though.  I've never done any further investigation of this issue.

Comment: @LoïcGammaitoni Also, don't forget Alloy runs in Java. There are some potential non-deterministic JVM factors playing roles, like JIT-compilation, and garbage collection, although they're unlikely to be the cause by themselves.